# Laravel logging out on user deleting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3.

I have an `User` model extending `Authenticatable`.

I also have an `users` panel where the super user can update and delete other users.

However, every time the super user deletes another user, he gets disconnected (logged out) from the system. How can I workaround this?

I am deleting on a custom controller "UserController":

```
public function delete (User $user)
    {
        $deleted = $user->delete();
        return compact('deleted');
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code regarding how you are deleting any user.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Are you saying that when the super user performs this action, they are logged out, or the user whom was deleted is logged out?

Comment: The "deleter" gets logged out when deleting the "deleted".

Comment: That's odd. No idea why that would happen given the above code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

When **creating** a new User using the built-in `make:auth` register method, the logged user inevitably gets re-logged as the recently created user. So, the logged user was no more the "super user" but the recently created user that, when deleted, gets logged out. Solved by registering in another method.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing any of your error logs, I'm not aware of Laravel's ability to return a variable from its controllers directly.  So unless this feature exists, the issue may (at its core), be occurring due to the line:

```
return compact('deleted');
```

Try to return a view with the variable attached, (e.g. - if your view resides in `resources/views/users/index.blade.php`), replace the aforementioned line with the following:

```
return view('users.index', compact('deleted'));
```

Comment: The `deleted` object is returned to JavaScript. When the JS callback see that `deleted == true` then the js properly returns the success message. I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem, as I use it in many other `delete()` methods. But only on `User` model deleting this happens.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't aware it was a method called through JS.

Comment: Yes, it's really strange that the not modified user gets affected. But thanks for your help!